# strange behaviour with javascript map/object

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript map to store keys and values. Later on I check if specified key is present in map or not, but it sometimes gives correct result but sometimes it don't. I tried to print the map using `console.log(mapname)`, it shows all keys, but if I try to check if some specified key is present - sometimes it gives wrong answer.

Am using following code:

```
// following code is called n times in loop with different/same vales of x
myMap : new Object();
var key = x  ; // populated dynamically actually
myMap[key] = "dummyval";
if(myIdMap[document.getElementById("abc").value.trim()] != null)
    alert('present');
else
    alert('not present');
```

What can be the possible problem? Can alphanumericstring/integers values can be used as keys?

Comment: Can we see the context that you're using this? Where is `myMap` defined (looks like in an object literal)? How is `x` created (is it a global or passed as an argument somehow)? You also said that sometimes same values are passed in as `x`... the resulting value associated with the old value of `x` will be destroyed when you do that, of course. But we could really use more detail. It's hard to diagnose an issue like this with so little to go by.

Comment: there are several syntax/reference errors in that code. can you post the actual code you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have to store keys in some temporary table or objects like session or cookies for future retrieve.
you have dynamically store x position value in mymap[key] but every time it loads and overwrite your new values. you something doing wrong there..

Comment: thanks for replying, but the problem if i print map it shows me proper keys, and i check if that key is present it doesnot work properly.

Comment: problem is it prints "not presnt" for keys which are present

Comment: you can check by alert -> myIdMap[document.getElementById("abc").value.trim()] and check what values exactly comes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMap = {};
// ...

//simulating your inner loop; is this close enough?
//Note: A MacGuffin is a plot device to move the story forward. 
//  Like a time machine, or a space ship.
for (var key in macGuffin) { 
    myMap[key] = macGuffin.processItem(key);
}

// ... 
var myKey = document.getElementById("abc").value.trim();
//Note the use of !==; false == null == 0 == '', but null only === null
if (myMap[myKey]!==null)  
//Better?  (typeof myMap[myKey] != 'undefined')
    console.log('present');
else
    console.log('not present');
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're aware that the value stored with the key could be null, as the following code shows:

```
a = {
   "mykey": null
}

for (x in a) {
   if (a[x] == null) {
      alert(x + " is null!");
   }
} // produces a single alert: "mykey is null!"
```